# Что за Element.prototype?

Tags: javascript

Что такое **Element.prototype?**

Искал инфу 2 часа в инете, но так и не нашел нужную мне инфу.

Нашел лишь Object.prototype, но не Element.prototype.

Пример ниже:

```js
Element.prototype.Hi = function() {
alert(`Привет, я ${this.tagName}`);
};

document.body.Hi(); 
document.documentElement.Hi();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Element` по сути является "родителем" для всех видов элементов, как `Object` - для всех объектов. Более подробнее читайте в документации [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element)

А что такое прототипы, читайте тут - [Прототипы объектов](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes)

Comment: Родитель же будет document разве не?

Comment: Про Element там есть, а про Element.prototype ничего не сказано(

Comment: добавил ссылку в ответе.

Comment: Воо спасибо, то что искал =)